# What happened to Rosie Betzler?

Tags: plot-explanation, jojo-rabbit

Why did Rosie Betzler (Scarlett Johansson's character) commit suicide in the movie ***JoJoRabbit***? She had many responsibilities in that movie. No clear reason or clue was given, except that one scene where she was distributing pamphlets to everyone's door.

Did anyone know why? Or was she hanged by the SS/army?

Comment: I have not seen the movie, but based on the plot summary at wikipedia I don't see how you could think that she committed suicide.  There is a scene where the mother and son see people hung in the town square for doing "what they could" to resist the NAZI government.  She is shown resisting the NAZI government by hiding a Jewish girl and handing out "Free Germany" pamphlets.  And she is later shown hanging in the same town square where other people were hung as punishment for resisting the government.  Is the wiki plot summary incorrect?

Comment: Oh makes sense, Sounds accurate but they didn't show her getting caught. And certain scenes in the movie had german scripts in the background without anyone speaking. Maybe that's what the german stuff meant. I thought people who didn't want to participate in the war committed suicide.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rosie did not commit suicide. According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jojo_Rabbit#Plot) and [themoviespoiler](http://themoviespoiler.com/movies/jojo-rabbit/) Jojo:

> finds his mother has been hanged in the town square.

This is foreshadowed in earlier scenes:

1. The older boys at the Hitler Youth training camp claim that Jojo's father is a coward.
2. Jojo "sees his mother hanging 'free Germany' posters around town."
3. The Gestapo clearly suspect Rosie of treason, as they search her house.

Comment: > Gestapo clearly suspect Rosie of treason, as they search her house They search her house *after* they hang her. Captain K. brings back her bicycle when the Gestapo is in Betzlers' house and tries to warn Jojo not to go outside, so that he wouldn't discover his mother in the town square.

Answer (score 4):

Raj already has the answer - Rosie did not commit suicide, she was hanged by the authorities for treason - but there's one additional clue as to how/why she was found out by the authorities.

The leaflet pinned to her leg in the hanging scene is the same as the one she put on the café table earlier, when she was seen by Jojo in his 'robot' outfit.
Roughly translates as, *"Liberate Germany. Fight the party"*. Clearly a seditious act.

[image]

[image]

[image]